# AngularJS $q all method executed early

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am having an angular js application that makes tons of `$http` requests. I want to do some action after all `$http` requests are completed.

So I am depending upon AngularJS `$q` service. I am using `$q` like this

```
$q.all(promiseArray).then(function(){
    //code to run after all services are completed.
})
```

The problem here is `$q` got executed even before all promises are added to the `promiseArray`. I have a very lengthy complex code that runs in a `forloop` and the promises are added inside that loop.

**Code Sample**

```
$q.all(ParentServiceArray).then(function() {
  angular.forEach(tData, function(v,k) {
   angular.forEach(v, function(value,key) {
    if(value[0].xxx.results) {
     angular.forEach(value[0].xxx.results, function(val,kk) {
       childServiceArray.push(HTTP_SERVICE_CALL.then(function(response){
        if(response.data.xx && response.data.xx == YYY){
        //logic                                 
        } else {
        //logic
        }
       }))
     })
    }
  })
 })
}
```

And the code snippet to run after all service call

```
$q.all(ParentServiceArray, ChildServiceArray).then(function() {
//Code to run after all services are completed              
})
```

The problem I believe is because of those repetitive `foreach` loops and `service` calls inside the loop, even before all promises are added to the `ChildServiceArray`, `$q.all` is executed.

Is there any workaround to fix this issue? I want this `$q` to wait till all promises are added to the promise array.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't really expect to be able to push stuff to a `$q` after it's `.then` executes and expect for it to wait for those too. By that time _it's done waiting_, `.then` already executed.

Comment: Is there any workaround for it? I need this $q.all to wait till all promises are added to the array.

Comment: Build another `$q` and push the new ones to that.

Comment: By that time the first $q.all will be executed, I don't want that to happen, I need the code to run only after all the service calls are completed.

Comment: But if some of your service calls depend on responses from other service calls there's absolutely no way of combining them in a single `$q`. I don't see why doing a first set of calls, waiting for them to finish, generating a second set of calls based on responses from the first set and then waiting for this second set and only `.then` running whatever code you need is a problem.

Comment: There must be some workaround like $timeout which I am expecting.

Comment: No, there is no workaround. How long is the `$timeout` supposed to be?